# Get the last records from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

[My tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9atcN.jpg)

```
    $sql="SELECT *
          FROM addresses
          LEFT JOIN users ON address_id = user_id
          LEFT JOIN notes ON note_id = user_id
          ORDER BY id DESC
          LIMIT 1";
```

This is my SQL query, my task is to show the last records from 3 tables, but the table is blank, I don't know why,thanks in advance people :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show us your db tables

Comment: View the hyperlink above the code.

Comment: You really have some weird db structure and where is `id` in these tables?

Comment: IDs are `ua_id`, `user_id`, `address_id`. The structure doesn't look weird to me.

Comment: @JimWright `ORDER BY id DESC` What's `id` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is coming from the  `ORDER BY id DESC` .
Indeed, you have no column so called id. 
You should probably remove this clause, in order to make your code work.

If you want to take the last records anyway, you can put an  `ORDER BY address_id DESC`  which will do the job !

The code directly edited :

```
      $sql="SELECT *
      FROM addresses
      LEFT JOIN users ON address_id = user_id
      LEFT JOIN notes ON note_id = user_id
      ORDER BY adress_id DESC
      LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Thank you,and what about showing the last record from each table ?

Comment: No problem ;), from the 4 tables or the 3 you just mentioned in your query ?

Comment: The 3 that just I mentioned

Comment: Oh, ok, have a nice day :) !

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
SELECT a.address_id, u.user_id, n.note_id
FROM addresses a
LEFT JOIN users_addresses ua ON ua.ua_address_id = a.address_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ua.ua_user_id
LEFT JOIN notes n ON n.note_user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY a.address_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Empty table dude

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to get all data from all the tables, not sure what do you mean last records from 3 tables, I can see four tables there:

```
SELECT *
FROM `addresses`
LEFT JOIN `users_addresses` ON `users_addresses`.`ua_address_id` = `addresses`.`address_id`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `users_addresses`.`ua_user_id`
LEFT JOIN `notes` ON `notes`.`note_user_id` = `users`.`user_id`;
```

Comment: I want the last record from users,the last from addresses and the last from notes in one table.I have already show all the data in another file .